# SQL Fill a column value based on two other columns

Tags: sql, select, view, grouping

This site has been a lifesaver way too many times.

Need some help again from you guys.

I am working on creating a query that will group all users to their respective group ids. Here is what I have:

```
UserID # UserLastName # GroupID # Section #

  01   #    Smith     #  999    #    1

  02   #    Smith     #  999    #    2

  03   #    White     #  999    #    1

  04   #    White     #  1000   #    2

  05   #    White     #  1000   #    3
```

and so forth...

What I want to do is to automatically assign Smith to only one group and section without overwriting what I already have. The group would be something like 999-S (Section is now the last name). And since White only belongs to one section of 999 he would simply return a 999-W.

I am thinking that a view or even a simple select should do this.

Not sure where to begin though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to create an Update query or just a Select query?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i totally understand your question but have this a try:

```
Create View WithGroupName
AS
SELECT UserID, 
       UserLastname, 
       GroupID, 
       Section, 
       GroupID + '-' + SUBSTRING(UserLastName,1,1) As GroupSection
FROM tableName
```

Comment: This works quite well. I would like to further complicate this by using a reverse substring on Groupid (2 characters). Can this be done?